# How to host opengts tracking system on a web domain

Tags: java, jsp, opengts

I have compiled a program from open source, I do not know how to upload it to the web domain.please help me experts
 like

Comment: Please give more information.  What is the program.  Where and why do you want to upload it.

Comment: Dear Obroimos 
I have a domain with fatcow.com I need my opengts tracking software which is open source, to be hosted. under my domain ogytrack.com kindly help me

Comment: I don't understand how to host  jsp